# The problem of not displaying validation messages in allauth after overriding allauth templates in django

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Hello I use the allauth package to validate forms. The problem I have in this case is that I want to change the default templates of the allauth package and add my own styles and css classes to them. And I have done this, but my problem is that when the user enters incomplete or incorrect login information, no validation message is displayed to the user. I want to change the default allauth templates, such as login.html, signup.html, etc. and also I want to display my own authentication messages. Please guide step by step I because am learning Django, Thanks.

This is login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load account socialaccount %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Sign In" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <h1 class="head-line">{% trans "Sign In" %}</h1>

    {% get_providers as socialaccount_providers %}

    {% if socialaccount_providers %}
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-center">{% blocktrans with site.name as site_name %}Please sign in with one
                of your existing third party accounts. Or, <a href="{{ signup_url }}">sign up</a>
                for a {{ site_name }} account and sign in below:{% endblocktrans %}
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="socialaccount_ballot container">

            <ul class="socialaccount_providers text-center border">
                {% include "socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html" with process="login" %}
            </ul>

            <div class="login-or text-center mt">{% trans 'or' %}</div>

        </div>

        {% include "socialaccount/snippets/login_extra.html" %}

    {% else %}
        <p>{% blocktrans %}If you have not created an account yet, then please
            <a href="{{ signup_url }}">sign up</a> first.{% endblocktrans %}</p>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="container">
        <form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_username">Username: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_username" name="login" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_password">Password: </label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="id_password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            {{ form.username }}
            {% if redirect_field_value %}
                <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}"/>
            {% endif %}
            <a class="button secondaryAction"
               href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">{% trans "Forgot Password?" %}</a>
            <button class="primaryAction btn btn-block mt mb" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

This is signup.html

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Signup" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1 class="head-line">{% trans "Sign Up" %}</h1>

    <p class="text-center">{% blocktrans %}Already have an account? Then please <a href="{{ login_url }}">sign in</a>.{% endblocktrans %}
    </p>

    <div class="container">
        <form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_username">Username: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_username" name="login" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_email">Email: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_username" name="email" placeholder="Emial">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_password1">Password: </label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="id_username" name="password1" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_password2">Password Again: </label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="id_username" name="password2" placeholder="Password Again">
            </div>
            {% if redirect_field_value %}
                <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}"/>
            {% endif %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block mb">{% trans "Sign Up" %} &raquo;</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is logout.html

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Sign Out" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1 class="head-line">{% trans "Sign Out" %}</h1>

    <p class="text-center">{% trans 'Are you sure you want to sign out?' %}</p>

    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'account_logout' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if redirect_field_value %}
                <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}"/>
            {% endif %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block mb">{% trans 'Sign Out' %}</button>
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```